# Setting the initial range for AMCharts ScrollBar

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have implemented a serial chart using [AMCharts](http://amcharts.com) but have more columns than can be realistically shown in a window.  To reduce the amount drawn, I have added a `ChartsScrollBar` which does the trick, but initially it selects all the data.  Does anyone know how to set the initial zoom for the scroll bar?

I've written a JSFiddle to explain the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/Wd3GM/

I'm trying to get the 'zoom bar' to show less than four item on startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should listen fot "init" event and then use one of the available zoom methods. Here is modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wd3GM/1/